# DateTime.FromFileTime returns date as 1/2/1601 C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datetime, blazor

I am trying to retrieve a Last modified date from a URL in a blazor website. Unfortunately , it returns the date as `01/02/1601` and not the actual last modified date.
I am using the following :

```
LastModified = DateTime.FromFileTime(element.LastModified)
```

This returns the date as `01/02/1601`.

Does anyone have a solution or idea why it is happening ?

Comment: That time is the default value for that method, are you sure the value you are retrieving isn't null?

Comment: Windows FileTime counts the number of 100-ns intervals since 1601-01-01. Your blazor element is probably using something else, possibly Unix time (seconds since 1970-01-01)? What is the value of element.LastModified?

Comment: @jhambright - Its not retrieving null

Comment: @pmcoltrane - the value of element.LastModified is showing 1661498279186

Comment: Have a look at [DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.fromunixtimemilliseconds?view=net-6.0)

Comment: why do you use `FromFileTime` if the input is not Windows file time?

Comment: I'm guessing `element.LastModified` value is in a different format than your systems `DateTime`. Try parsing it while supplying the format of the input `DateTime.ParseExact(element.LastModified, "LastModifiedDateFormatHere",null);`

Comment: The DateTime.FromFileTime(Int64) method is used to convert the specified Windows file time to the equivalent local time. Does your project request server modification times to be returned in Razor pages?